# Как можно узнать высоту Laoyut?

Tags: android, android-layout

Я сам назначаю ему высоту по контенту, но я хочу узнать его высоту в `dp` или пикселях, чтобы при смене контента оставить высоту таким же какой и был.

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fr.getLayoutParams();
params.height = -2;
fr.setLayoutParams(params);
```

И еще вопрос: если я назначу

```
params.height = 100;
```

в чем это значение измеряется - в `px` или `dp`?

Comment:     
> В чем это значение измеряется в px или dp?  

px

Comment: даже если я делаю измерение в onResume возвращает по нулям


        @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        int topYcoord=fr.getTop();
        int bottomYcoord=fr.getBottom();
        Log.i("height", topYcoord + "  " + bottomYcoord);
        fr.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        Log.i("height", fr.getMeasuredHeight() + " " + fr.getMeasuredWidth());
    }

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да так и делал,  назначал пиксели вручную, но он все равно возвращает по нулям.

Comment: @eldqs, обновил ответ.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Большое спасибо, буду с ним выкручиваться, а разве можно фрагмент засунуть в RelaytiveLayout

Comment: @eldqs, насколько я знаю, запихнуть фрагмент можно в любого подкласс ViewGroup.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо

Comment: @eldqs, you're welcome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведённый вами в вопросе код спокойно вернёт в

```
params.height
```

высоту элемента.

Проблема может возникнуть, если она изначально

```
= "wrap_content" || "match_parent"; //вернёт -2 || -1, а не высоту в пикселях
```

Тогда вариантов несколько. Например можно получить координаты "верха" и "низа" элемента:

```
FrameLayout fr = //находим элемент
int topYcoord = fr.getTop();
int bottomYcoord = fr.getBottom();
```

И из них вычислить высоту элемента:

```
int calculatedHeight = bottomYcoord-topYcoord;
```

И применить к элементу:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fr.getLayoutParams();
params.height = calculatedHeight;
fr.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**UPD 0:**

Всё вышеописанное работает в `onResume()` активити, когда система подсчитала все координаты всех лэйаутов.

До onResume() можно, например так:

```
//int h = fr.getMeasuredHeight(); вернёт 0, т.к. не измерялось ещё.
//вроде как принудительно измеряет элемент
//"0" здесь - это какие-то константы. Что и как они конкретно делают - магия для меня
fr.measure(0,0);
//теперь высота измерена и вернет !0
int h = fr.getMeasuredHeight();
```

**UPD 1:**

Поэкспериментировал. Выводы:

1. FrameLayout возвращает 0 всегда, если в нём нет детей.
2. Если есть ребёнок, возвращает его высоту, даже если он (ребёнок) занимает его не полностью.
3. С RelativeLayout всё работает.

**Вывод:**
Пользуйте RelativeLayout.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, к сожалению они что верх, что низ возвращают по 0, что можно сделать?

Comment: Не за что)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вообще-то проблема еще осталась, 

    int topYcoord=fr.getTop();
    int bottomYcoord=fr.getBottom();

они возвращают по нулям

Comment: Нули возвращает, если я не ошибаюсь, если пользовать это до onResume() активити. Ща ответ обновлю.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, к сожалению, она так же возвращает по нулям, я все это делаю во фрагменте, то есть внутри фрагмента находится framelayout и все происходит в onCreateView.

Comment:     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle l) {
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(setNewListUserOfOperator));
        final View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, null);
        FrameLayout fr = (FrameLayout) content.findViewById(R.id.frgmCont);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = null;
            params =  fr.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = -2;
            fr.setLayoutParams(params);
        fr.measure(0,0);
        int heght = fr.getMeasuredHeight();

Comment: @eldqs, быть может у вас в **fr** ничего нет? У меня этот код используется и работает. Попробуйте назначить высоту в пикселях и потом измерить:

      FrameLayout fr = (FrameLayout) content.findViewById(R.id.frgmCont);
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = null;
        params =  fr.getLayoutParams();
    //если назначить "-2", т.е. LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, а в элементе ничего нет, то высота будет =0
        params.height = 42;
        fr.setLayoutParams(params);
       fr.measure(0,0);
       int heght = fr.getMeasuredHeight();